# How do I create a realistic Waterfall?

Tags: photorealism

I had the idea to create a realistic environment with a waterfall but my problem is, that on YouTube there isn’t a good tutorial and with a flip fluids simulation it doesn’t look that real. Somebody know how to make a waterfall?

Comment: Try [this](https://youtu.be/37KbJOb3C24) quick tutorial by Grant Abbitt. There's also [this](https://youtu.be/1U2sNvJHKAA) one which uses geometry nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Comment: The second link may be more suitable for your requirement as it's quite flexible.